# How to properly structure vue / node app when using instagram api

Tags: node.js, vue.js, vuejs2, instagram-api

So I have an application that requires the use of connecting to the instagram api, fetching user data, and displaying that data.

My application needs to work like this: use is on a page where he/she clicks a "connect" button. They are then connected to the instagram api, and REMAIN on the same page. The page is then populated with their current instagram information.

Currently, I have a project which is structured like this:

```
myapp
--client // All Vue.js files in here
--server // All server endpoints here. ALSO WHERE INSTAGRAM CONNECTION HAPPENS
```

I ran into a little hiccup while following [this](https://medium.com/@vshelestovskyi/instagram-authentication-with-node-js-and-mongodb-edfb7b6065ad) which is just a tutorial on how to settup user auth with node/ instagram api.

In my server project, I have a router.js:

```
const AuthenticationController = require('./controllers/AuthenticationController')
const AuthenticationControllerPolicy = require('./policies/AuthenticationControllerPolicy')
const config = require('./config/config.js')

module.exports = (app) => {
  app.post('/register', AuthenticationControllerPolicy.register, AuthenticationController.register)
  app.post('/login', AuthenticationController.login)

  //BELOW IS TAKEN FROM TUTORIAL MENTIONED ABOVE. 
  app.get('/auth/instagram', function (request, response) {
    console.log(`REDIRECT URI ${config.instagram.authURL}`)
    response.redirect(config.instagram.authURL)
  })

  app.get('/auth/confirmed', function (request, response) {
    console.log(`ARE WE IN HERE?????  ${request.query.code}`)
    response.send(request.query.code)
  })
}
```

If I go to my server port: `http://localhost:8081/auth/instagram` I can see that connecting to instagram works, and Im redirected to the confirmation page, and the code is displayed as expected.

**MY ISSUE/QUESTION** is now... how do I connected that back to my client application? Now that my server has that data, how do I send that data back to my client app?

My component is simple right now:

```
<template>
  <v-container>
    <v-layout>
      <v-flex xs6>
        <panel title="Connect To Instagram">
          <form
            name="ig-connect-form"
            <v-btn
              dark
              class="red lighten-1"
              @click="connect">
              Connect
            </v-btn>
          </form>
        </panel>
      </v-flex>
    </v-layout>
  </v-container>
</template>

<script>
import AuthenticationService from '@/services/AuthenticationService'

export default {
  data () {
    return {
      igusername: '',
      password: '',
      error: null
    }
  },
  methods: {
    async connect () {
      try {
        // This triggers the connection on my server.... how do I get data back from different server route now??
        console.log(response)
      } catch (error) {
        this.error = error.response.data.error
      }
    }
  }
}
</script>

<style scoped>
</style>
```

Do I require setting up vue server side rendering? Is there a simpler way of just having my client app watch for data at the auth/confirmation port on my server app? Hope this is clear. im trying to keep as concise as possible.

Answer (score 0):

You don't send the data from the server to the client, but instead make a request from the client to the server which then answers with the data. However, a couple of more steps is required.

Something like this:

1. Client clicks connect
2. Client is redirected to the auth page
3. Client authenticates with Instagram
4. Client is redirected back to your site with code=xxxxxxxx in the URL
5. Server uses that code to get an access token from the Instagram API
6. Server saves the access token for this specific user
7. Server can now make queries to the Instagram API with that access token
8. Client can now ask the server for whatever data and display it on the page

Comment: Thanks!... question....Step 3 so how do I display that auth step to user if its happening from server? Example, currently when i click connect button from localhost:8080/console (client) no redirect happens. But when I go to localhost:8081/auth/instagram (server) i get correctly redirected to localhost:8080/console?code (client). Form server logs I can see client is hitting server... but client itself is not updating. Maybe I need to add someting to handle displaying console/* wildcard?